# Copy and save files/images

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing a list of urls to images/doc files which I would like to loop through to download and save to disk..  Can anyone tell me if I can do that in an sql script and if so give me a hint?

Many thanks,

Derek

Comment: Use a scripting language for this.

Comment: powershell is way to go

Comment: This is like asking "I need to shape gemstones, primarily diamonds.. Can anyone tell me if I can do that with my bulldozer?" SQL is for manipulating record sets. It's not a good fit for scripting webscrapes.

Comment: Thank you Dmitrij..  I followed your hint all the way to success using Powershell..  Please can you post an 'answer' and I will accept it and show my workings..

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Python, Ruby, Perl or Powershell.  Use one of them to grab the URLS, scrape, and insert back into SQL.  Using pure SQL would be very challenging to write, but possible.  Just like you can paint a house with a hammer, it's possible but not the right tool for the job.  However if you insist, you could do something like:

- write dynamic SQL to loop and generate `xp_cmdshell` code
- run that dynamic SQL which will call something like `wget` that downloads the data you want into a format you can `BCP`
- write additional dynamic SQL that *somehow* uses `xp_cmdshell` to `BCP` the data in

Comment: Thank you for your comments sniperd